# Regex matching a group that may or may not exist on string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a text which contains somewhere in the middle the following strings:

1. Sat28 B158 RGX 1100 1200
2. Sat28 Hoover 0005 RGX B158 RGX 1100 1200

I want to capture only the following groups:

1. Sat28 B158 RGX 1100 1200
2. Sat28 B158 RGX 1100 1200

To find the first option I've come up with the following regex:

```
(\w{3}\d{2})\s+([B]\d{3})\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{4})
```

Example: https://regexr.com/772aq
(Only the first option is included within the text)

However, when trying to find the second option as well, I've added a non-capturing group, which in turn skips the first option:

```
(\w{3}\d{2})\s+(?:hoover\s+\d{4}\s+RGX\s+)(\[B]\d{3})\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{4})
```

Example: https://regexr.com/772at
(Both options are included within the text, but only match the second option)

Basically, I added a non-capturing group (?:) that looks (and should ignore) the word hoover, blank space, 4 digits, blank space, the word RGX, blank space.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: text added to the regexr.com's examples for clarification.

Comment: Hello, text added to the Regexr examples to clarify what I'm trying to achieve. It's not line by line, rather it's within a text. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you should just make the group optional `(\w{3}\d{2})\s+(?:hoover\s+\d{4}\s+RGX\s+)?([B]\d{3})\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d{4})\s+(\d{4})`. Also not quite sure why you have escaped the `[` just before the `B` but maybe it was a typo.

Comment: That was it! Indeed the 'B' doesn't need to be escaped. Thank you for your help.